# Add comment to a post

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem when I add a comment to a post, I get this error:

> Call to undefined method App\User::comments()

My controller:

```
public function addComment(Request $request) {
    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->comment = $request['commentText'];
    if($request->user()->comments()->save($comment)) {
        return redirect()->route('profile')->with('success', 'Your comment was successfully added.');
    }
    else if(!$request->user()->comments()->save($comment)) {
        return redirect()->route('profile')->with('danger', 'Something went wrong.');
    }
}
```

My route:

```
Route::get('/viewUserQuestion/{post}', 'PostsController@viewUserQuestion')->name('viewQuestion');

Route::post('/viewQuestion/{post}', 'CommentsController@addComment');
```

My blade:

```
 <form class="" action="{{url('viewQuestion/{post}')}}" id="addComment" method="post">
                    @csrf;
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="commentText" placeholder="write a comment..." rows="3"></textarea>
                        <br>
                        < <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I have tried all the ways but they are not successful.

Comment: can you show us your User model?

Comment: This is weird. You are attempting to save twice. That makes no sense

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi he don't even need that second if

Comment: your model please

Comment: I solved but now I have this SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `comments` (`comment`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (asdsad, 1, 2020-04-04 13:26:48, 2020-04-04 13:26:48)) User ID to store the user id

Comment: @STRKLok just set 'user_id' => $request->user()->id , and don't forget to set it fillable in Comment model